# Deploying Vite build: i am not getting all the html pages

Tags: build, vite

After building my vite file, my zipcode.html is not included. How do I fix?
My zipcode.html is in the same folder as the index.html.

vite v4.4.9 building for production...
✓ 4 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                       5.91 kB │ gzip: 2.06 kB
dist/assets/beer-bg-2afb37de.png    745.23 kB
dist/assets/pub-ed9c72f3.jpg      6,690.82 kB
dist/assets/index-c6e7ebc5.css        1.62 kB │ gzip: 0.69 kB
dist/assets/index-e42e5016.js         1.91 kB │ gzip: 0.78 kB
✓ built in 201ms

Comment: vite v4.4.9 building for production...
✓ 4 modules transformed.
dist/assets/zipcode-2849b97f.html      2.51 kB │ gzip: 1.14 kB
dist/index.html                        5.97 kB │ gzip: 2.08 kB
dist/assets/beer-bg-2afb37de.png     745.23 kB
dist/assets/pub-ed9c72f3.jpg       6,690.82 kB
dist/assets/index-c6e7ebc5.css         1.62 kB │ gzip: 0.69 kB
dist/assets/index-e42e5016.js          1.91 kB │ gzip: 0.78 kB
✓ built in 197ms
applej1@Jerrys-MBP TheBrewery %

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to find:

Create a vite.config.js file at the root of project and put this in it.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: './index.html',
        about: './about.html',
        shaderOne: './shaderOne.html',
        // ...
        // List all files you want in your build
      }
    }
  }
})
```